# Azure Function app (.NET 8) not logging info to app insights

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a .NET 8 Azure Function app which I have been working on, this is the first .NET 8 app that I have created, though I have worked on function apps since .NET Core 3.1.

I'm sure this is something really basic that I am missing, but I can't see what.

This is my `host.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "debug"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the function:

```
[Function("MYFUNCNAME")]
public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
{
    _logger.LogError("LOCAL THIS IS AN ERROR MESSAGE WHICH IS LOGGED");
    
    _logger.LogInformation($"THIS WONT BE LOGGED IN AI - THOUGH IT DOES SHOW IN THE CONSOLE");

    _logger.LogDebug("THIS IS NOT LOGGED EITHER");
}
```

In the console I can see ALL of the messages.

However in app insights I can only see the error messages.

I want all of the messages in AI as well as in the console.

I am at a loss, I have another function app which has the same configuration and it works perfectly. I cant see any difference between configurations in the function app or app insights between the working and non working projects (except the working one is on .NET 6 and the non working one is on .NET 8).

What could I be missing here?

Comment: What does "the same config is in use in my other function app" mean?  You didn't include anything on how the app insights resources are configured.  If the code configurations are identical, but the Azure resource configuration is responsible this is getting outside an appropriate question for this venue.

Comment: Perhaps that is not worded very well, Ill edit it - but what it means is that I have more than one azure function app that I am working on, the configuration in the hosts file on both projects is identical yet one project works (Logs info messages to ai) and the other doesn't. It COULD be something that is misconfigured in AI - but I dont know what - thats kind of what the question is getting at, I have set up AI and the function app exactly the same way as I have in the past and yet the new one doesnt work - what could I have missed that would cause the issue I am seeing?

Comment: App Insights has a lot of configuration on about what gets retained, including which levels and keeping only a sample (again, dependent on log levels).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, As I stated, Im looking for guidance on where that would be configured as I have never needed to change that before and afaik all of that config is in the host.json.

Comment: That's getting outside the bounds of an acceptable question here.  This isn't an azure support forum.  It's for things related to developing software, not deployment and infrastructure maintenance.

Comment: Not really as we're yet to establish where the problem lies - It could very well be an issue with the function app.

I'm guessing from your responses that you don't know either, so thanks for the comments they were not helpful but Ill keep everything you said in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue with .net7 Functions in Isolated Mode, I'd guess your old function app did not run in isolated mode and the new one does?

If that is the case then you need configure the `LogFilterOptions` and remove the `ApplicationInsightsLoggingProvider`

This is done in your hostBuilder (found in program.cs)

You just need to add the following after the `services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights()` call.

```
services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
{
    var appInsightsLoggerProvider = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

    if (appInsightsLoggerProvider != default) options.Rules.Remove(appInsightsLoggerProvider);
});
```

Its not very well documented, at least I didn't think so, but if you google "azure functions dotnet isolated process guide" there is a microsoft learn page which talks about the isolated model - its not explicitly talked about in there *BUT* one of the code samples (in the startup and configuration section) includes something very similar to the code above.

After that it should work.